# How i can handle network disconnect using RxJava 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have some problems, which bound with lose of network connection. How i can handle it in RxJava 2? Thank you very much.

i have this method:

```
Disposable disposable = api.setStatus(params)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnSubscribe(listener::onPreExecute)
            .doFinally(listener::onPostExecute)
            .subscribe(serviceRequest -> handleResponse(listener, serviceRequest), listener::onError);
```

//////////////

```
@POST("set_status")
Single<OrderResponse> setStatus(@FieldMap Map<String, String> params);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate problem statement/use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer after question was update:**

You can handle it in `doOnError` or your `listener::onError`:

```
Disposable disposable = api.setStatus(params)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnError(error->{
                    handleError(error)
                })
                .subscribe(serviceRequest -> handleResponse(listener, serviceRequest), listener::onError);

void handleError(Throwable error){
    if (error instanceof IOException){
        // handle network error
    } else {
        if(error instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
            // handle timeout error 
        }
    }


}
```

**Old answer about subscribing to connection change:**

For this purposes you need to catch the network connection change and dispatch it via `BehaviorSubject`.

Like this:

```
class NetworkManager(
        private val context: Context
) {
    private val state: BehaviorSubject<Boolean> = BehaviorSubject.create()

    private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(c: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            state.onNext(isConnected())
        }
    }

    init {
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)
        state.onNext(isConnected())
    }

    fun subscribe(): Observable<Boolean> {
        return state
    }

    fun isConnected(): Boolean {
        val cm = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val netInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
    }
}
```

Create this classs in your `Application` scope and it will be ok

Comment: Why not `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: Yes, `BehaviourSubject` seems better for this! Thanks! Edited answer

Comment: @MaratZangiev, thank you. I updated my question. Can you please explain to me, how i can apply your code?

Comment: checkout new answer

Answer (score 0):

if you return Single for network calls you can use the onErrorReturn method to catch error and return state to indicate network error.

Answer (score 0):

Handle in onError method as below

```
void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    if(throwable instanceof IOException) {
       //Handle network error
    }else if(throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
      //Handle Request timeout
    }else {
     //Show some error like something went wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: RxJava2 not considered SocketTimeoutException or IOException as a throwable, in other words onError not called

Comment: @AlexS OnError will get called for all kind of exceptions. Did you check by putting some Log or debugger in onError() ?